# Creating div overlays over any video (similar to Google ads in YouTube)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flash

I would like to create a div overlay over videos in a html page. The videos could be embedded YouTube videos, or from any other source. Any ideas on how to do this? I have done a similar task of overlaying divs on images but never did for videos. Would greatly appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Duplicate question. Solution can be found here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/3820325/555177

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure `wmode="Opaque"` or `wmode="Transparent"` is set on the video embed and the video will recognize its parents' `z-index` css property.

> [wmode](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html) - Possible values: window,
>   opaque, transparent. Sets the Window
>   Mode property of the Flash movie for
>   transparency, layering, and
>   positioning in the browser.

Comment: The script I am creating will be used over webpages I do not have access to. It dynamically detects videos and calculates their position and then sets the overlay. Can I set wmode property in such cases dynamically?

Comment: So are you saying the "web pages" are within a child (frame) on your current page?

Comment: No. This script would be used as a widget to display an overlay div for any webpage with video content. Say, you have a blog with embedded videos and you would like have a an overlaying div with some specific content over your videos. Then you should just be able  to include my script for that. Since I do not have access to your blog's source code, I would like to make it work on the fly.