# DIV overlay YouTube embed code

Tags: jquery, html, youtube, embed, overlay

I have an iframe inside a DIV and I would like to make the div draggable using jquery.  I've found that I can accomplish this if I absolute position both the DIV and Iframe and set the Z-index of the DIV higher than the iframe (I understand the content underneath is now inaccessible).

Is there a way to achieve the same with the YouTube embed code? What's happening is that as the player is flash it's appearing infront of the DIV and ignoring the z-index.

All help appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the parameter wmode=transparent to the embed code:

Possible duplicate and solution here [overlay opaque div over youtube iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820325/overlay-opaque-div-over-youtube-iframe)

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm.