# Div overlaying an iframe doesn't show up

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm having a problem with overlaying divs. It's not a z-index issue, but rather something to do with iframes.

After reading [How to show a div over a Youtube video (z-index)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016680/how-to-show-a-div-over-a-youtube-video-z-index), I tried adding `&wmode=opaque` to the urls on the src attr of the vimeo and youtube iframes.

This solved the problem once, but even when the code is the same, it didn't work for other iframes, and I don't know why. :S

This is the website: http://beacabrera.es

Hovering the menu at the top (scroll to see it) unveils a fixed div that should overlap the vimeo videos. There are two videos. It works with the first one, but not with second.

I encountered the same issue here: http://www.marshmallowsandgasoline.com. Same menu at the top (scroll a little to see it) but the submenu will not show up even though all videos on iframes have `&wmode=opaque`.

As an example, the way for showing and hiding the submenu items is on all cases as follows:

```
$("#menuitem")
.mouseenter(function(){
    $("#submenuitem").fadeIn("fast");
})
.mouseleave(function(){
    $("#submenuitem").fadeOut("fast");
});
```

And it works when there are no iframes involved.

I know there's always an answer to these problems. I'll appreciate any idea.

Thank you in advanced.

Bea.

Comment: first that site is epic...2nd that behavior is based on scroll position of page too and hidden deep somewhere.

Comment: in fact part really belong to reel section but i guess you want that menu to appear before portfolio section

Comment: You mean epic because of the epicSlider? ;) hehe. The menu should appear on reel section, before portfolio section. The scrolling there works fine. It's just that the submenu (the div that reveals when hovering the menu) is not showing when you're on the second video (the one with the purple background) but it works fine on the reel video (weird!).

Comment: at my computer it only shows when portfolio is like 90% in view. For first one. And it definitely doesn't show up when either, video 1&2, are in view.

Comment: $%&$"!%"%& - ok, thanx @MuhammadUmer. Could you please tell me what browser are you using?

Comment: Ok. I see it isn't working anymore here either. It was a while ago. I promise these things just get me on my nerves. I can't figure out how to fix it :(