# <iframe> not "hidden" by dialog modal

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a youtube video introduced by `<iframe>` tag (I tried by `<object>` also, but the results are the same). On the load page, I have a dialog modal also (that it works properly).

I don't understand why, only on IE11.0, this video is not "hidden" (meaning inactive, like all other elements of the site, until the window is closed).

Is it something special, particularly for IE, that I need to add in css? I tried z-index (only idea which I had), with negative values for this video, but it doesn't work. It is a bug of IE? I have no idea... 
Thanks in advance.

PS. If it is necessary, I can add the css file also (but it's a little big).
PS.2. I repeat, for other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari), this works properly (the video is inactive while the dialog modal is active (not closed).

Comment: By inactive you mean below the dialog?

Comment: Yes, in deed. All others elements (text links, photo links, menu bar) are below the dialog, except this video. It's happened only on IE.

Comment: Try to add ?wmode=opaque to the source of your video like it is suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016680/how-to-show-a-div-over-a-youtube-video-z-index

Comment: After rel=0 (I already had this) I added this &modestbranding=1&wmode=opaque" and now this work properly for all major browsers, included IE11.0. So, this is worked for me.Thanks a lot and Happy New Year 2015! to all members of this community.