# Youtube iframes sitting on top of fixed position element in Chrome

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube, fixed

In chrome youtube iframes float on top of my fixed position header.  I've tried setting z-indexes for both and its not happening.

Anybody know a fix for this?

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820325/overlay-opaque-div-over-youtube-iframe

add ?wmode=opaque to the iframe src url

Comment: I also needed `&rel=0`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you embed a youtube iframe like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/FSHDDteCBXw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The default wmode will make the video overlay everything else, the solution is just add 
?wmode=opaque in to the end of the src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/FSHDDteCBXw"

like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/FSHDDteCBXw?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: this is working in Firefox. but instead of the video it renders the player completely black...

Comment: If it's black, that's probably because you have a bad url. If there's already a ? in the url, you want to add `&wmode=opaque` instead of the ?