# Div is covered by youtube embed, how do I fix that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, youtube

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/DerNalia/vmNP4/

The gray menu in the top right is supposed to be above the videos. Why isn't it? How do I make it so the div is always on top of the videos, regardless of positions?

Comment: What browser? Firefox 7 has the gray div on top of the video.

Comment: possible duplicate of [overlay opaque div over youtube iframe :)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820325/overlay-opaque-div-over-youtube-iframe)

Comment: @Darcy - in google chrome it seem not to work.

Comment: @qxxx use the method described in the selected answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hm... I think i might be misunderstanding your question, but... What is exactly you mean? You want the gray div FIXED on top of every video or the gray div ABOVE the videos? (Not fixed on the screen corner)

If you want the div FIXED on the corner, and the videos are being on top of it, try to do this:

Find this attribute on the iframe tags of youtube videos:

```
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-nOOMpC7RwQ"
```

At the end of the url, add this: `?wmode=transparent`

It'd be like this:

```
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-nOOMpC7RwQ?wmode=transparent"
```