# Images placeholder getting stuck behind iframe (just on Windows machines)

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'm trying to get it so that the clicking the image will play the video underneath. It works absolutely fine in all Mac browsers - here...

http://jsfiddle.net/SparrwHawk/KtbYR/14/

But doesn't work on Windows at all. Maybe it's a Windows security thing, maybe iframes can't have anything underneath? Not sure why this happens. Can anyone offer a work around?

I'm looking to place a still image over a video - the ones that YouTube generate are often blurry, whereas if I place my own over there I can ensure it's of high quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `wmode=opaque` to the URL params.

Using your code: http://jsfiddle.net/KtbYR/15/

**EDIT:** See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4788044/77922) for an explanation