# Trap for click on IFRAME

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, popup

I have a an iframe which inside there is a video link from somwhere.
I want popup a div when click on iframe.

```
<a href="javascript:alert();" class="iframelink">
                <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zDNXx-PgU3k" width="213" height="195" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </a>


$('.iframelink').click(function(){   
         alert('iframe clicked. Open popup.'); 
})
```

How? But because is actually another page javascript cant catch click event.
Is there any way?

Comment: what click event are you trying to capture?

Comment: The mouse button is depressed while the pointer is inside the element.
The mouse button is released while the pointer is inside the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have to attach the handler on a link inside an iframe, you should find it inside the iframe. Try this.

```
$('a.iframelink iframe').contents()//Will get iframe contents
.find('videoLinkSelector')//Pass the required selector
.click(function(){
   //Write your code here
});
```

`contents()` reference: http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Note that you can only access iframe resources only if it is in the same domain as its parent page.

Comment: This won't work if the iframe content comes from another domain, because of same origin policy.

Comment: Yes, you cannot access any resource from other domain.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from being rather naughty and placing an invisible element over the top of your IFRAME (click-jacking), I think you're out of luck as I don't think events within the IFRAME bubble up at all. Careful here - you're in dangerous territory. Thar be monsters.

P.S. one option would be to have the IFRAME point to a page on your site, that you could add an onclick event to - which would then fire a function/event on the parent element - however you're still going to be out of luck when it comes to firing on clicking the FLASH object I think.

Comment: actually i want to display video inside a iframe but with small size. When user click iframe to run video i will popup a box and run video. i know but is there any workaround?

Comment: Ahh I see - I mistunderstood what you were trying to achieve. hunters' answer may be more suited. By the way, why do you need to show the video inside an iframe - you could show the videos thumbnail on your page and attach an onclick event to that surely?

Comment: of course. is there any way just show videos thumbnail from url inside a div?

Comment: You can get thumbnails for YouTube videos by using this URL: http://img.youtube.com/vi/<YouTube Video ID>/0.jpg 

0.jpg can be changed to 1.jpg for a smaller version of the image. You can either use that in an IMG tag, or set it as a background image in a DIV element and explicitly set a width and height to match the thumbnail image.

Comment: see following question and answer for more info about layering over IFRAMEs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4788044/683808

Answer (score 1):

You can try to leverage the YouTube API.

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Adding_event_listener

Though it is limited you may be able to do what you need to.

Comment: so, for other video provider what will i do? is there any generic solution when an iframe clicked make a handler?