# The embeded video hides dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I embeded a `youtube video` in the website. Now my problem is when i open any dialog window or

`jquery ui modal dialog` , the video hides that dialog. I tried to increse the `z-Index` of the `dilaog`,

but it not works. Can anybody have the solution for this problem?[image: My problems screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set wmode=opaque in falsh object attributes.

For Youtube [this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820325/overlay-opaque-div-over-youtube-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Use the option **'use old embed code'** on youtube and then add this inside object -

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque"></param>
```

That will set the Flash z-index lower.

```
<object width="420" height="315"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/G2zpWw_0Er4?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/G2zpWw_0Er4?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="420" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
```