# overlay opaque div over gametrailers iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, wmode

Recently gametrailers changed their embed code from:

```
<embed width="960" height="540" src="http://media.mtvnservices.com/mgid:moses:video:gametrailers.com:722265"  quality="high" bgcolor="000000" name="efp" align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"  pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"  flashvars="autoPlay=false"  allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
```

to

```
<iframe src="http://media.mtvnservices.com/embed/mgid:arc:video:gametrailers.com:0a115b6c-2d82-4a8c-b08b-4b6975e4c0dc" width="960" height="540" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The new embed code is just like the [youtube iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820325/overlay-opaque-div-over-youtube-iframe), and it overlays my lightbox.

With the old embed code I was able to add a wmode parameter and make it stay below the div:

```
<embed wmode="opaque" width="960" height="540" src="http://media.mtvnservices.com/mgid:moses:video:gametrailers.com:722265"  quality="high" bgcolor="000000" name="efp" align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"  pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"  flashvars="autoPlay=false"  allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
```

But the new code does not allow me to do anything to keep the iframe below, does anyone know of a solution to this or some hidden parameter that I missed?

Comment: use z-index & position absolute or relative on parent div

Comment: @SVS no effect in chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Temporary solution**

This is the old url to embed:

```
http://media.mtvnservices.com/mgid:moses:video:gametrailers.com:722265
```

This is the new url in the iframe:

```
http://media.mtvnservices.com/embed/mgid:arc:video:gametrailers.com:0a115b6c-2d82-4a8c-b08b-4b6975e4c0dc
```

As a temporary solution I change the iframe url to this undefined URL that I found by randomly tweaking the iframe url and embed this instead of using the iframe:

```
http://media.mtvnservices.com/mgid:arc:video:gametrailers.com:0a115b6c-2d82-4a8c-b08b-4b6975e4c0dc
```

It looks like this:

```
<embed wmode="opaque" width="550" height="350" src="http://media.mtvnservices.com/mgid:arc:video:gametrailers.com:0a115b6c-2d82-4a8c-b08b-4b6975e4c0dc"  quality="high" bgcolor="000000" name="efp" align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"  pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"  flashvars="autoPlay=false"  allowfullscreen="true"></embed>
```