# Flash content in iframe overlaying chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**In short**

Looking for a way to display position=fixed `div` on top of flash where the flash is inside an iframe.

**The Question**

I am currently developing a google chrome extension that displays a visual aid on top of the window.

Basically, this is a `<div>` tag with `position:fixed`.

The problem is some websites display flash content, and when my extension goes on top of those flash elements they overlay it. I would like to find a way to display my content on top of those flash elements.

**The Problem**

The flash is inside an iframe element, and has wmode set to window which means it overlays everything. However, I can not change the content of the flash element since it resides in a different domain (an attempt results in a same-origin error)

**What I would like to avoid**

I would like to avoid running the extension in every website and checking if its referrer is the site I'm running in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your question is very similar to this one: [overlay opaque div over youtube iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820325/overlay-opaque-div-over-youtube-iframe)

If I understand correctly, the issue can be resolved by adding the wmode=opaque parameter in your iframe embed. For example (with a youtube video):

**- HTML iframe embed**

***Make sure that the wmode=opaque parameter is the first parameter after the source url of the iframe (as mentioned here: [overlay opaque div over youtube iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820325/overlay-opaque-div-over-youtube-iframe))***

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="520" height="330" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/CMNry4PE93Y?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**- CSS**

```
#overlay {
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:#000;
opacity:0.8;
/*background:rgba(255,255,255,0.8); or just this*/
z-index:50;
color:#fff;
```

}

Comment: Actually, I'm running a chrome extension inside a webpage, however, I guess I can run (before $(document).ready hopefully) and change every src attribute of every iframe object to include ?wode=opaque . This is by far my best shot, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can execute a script in the context of an iframe like so:

```
var code = '[].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll("embed"), function(embed){embed.setAttribute("wmode", "transparent")});';

chrome.tabs.executeScript( tabRef, {

    code: code,

    allFrames: true //Executes the script in all frames


}, function() { });
```

This will find all the embed elements and set their `wmode` to `"transparent"` so that a html element can overlay them.

See: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi

Comment: Does this not require my extension to have permission to run in the iframe (meaning in a tld which is not on my list)?

Comment: Yeah it does require tabs and permissions, why is that a problem?

Comment: The extension has permission to run on a list of ~ 30 sites. However the flash content is in an iframe residing in another site.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You could use these permissions: `"permissions": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "tabs"
    ]`

Comment: I know I can, but the user will be notified the extension will have all access to all websites and not just these 30. Is there no way to avoid this?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Nope, you need to have permissions to access the iframe sorry. But access all sites is less intimidating than a list of 30 sites, probably :P