# Css3 transitions working in chrome only, doesn't work in safari and mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

Css3 transitions working in chrome only, doesn't work in safari and mozilla.

Here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Fade-in/Fade-out animation</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Style for button */
        #myBtn
        {
            width:80px;
        }

        /* Style for image */
        #mainFrame
        {
            -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
            -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
            -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
        }
        #mainFrame.fade-out
        {
            opacity:0;
        }
        #mainFrame.fade-in
        {
            opacity:1;
        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fade(btnElement) {
            if (btnElement.value === "Fade Out") {
                document.getElementById("mainFrame").className = "fade-out";
                btnElement.value = "Fade In";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("mainFrame").className = "fade-in";
                btnElement.value = "Fade Out";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Simple fade-in/fade-out example</h3>
    <input id="myBtn" type="button" value="Fade Out" onclick="fade(this);" />

    <iframe id="mainFrame" width="300" height="400" frameborder="0" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/rT_OmTMwvZI"
                            allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `btnElement.value == "Fade Out"` instead of `btnElement.value === "Fade Out"`.

Comment: can you add a fiddle demo for it?

Comment: wait, It do apply className but don't make the transition effect or it neither applies the className?

Comment: @SaurabhLP using jsfiddle  won't be able to test browser compatibility.Simply copy paste the whole code and try browsing using chrome and mozilla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include also `transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;` in your `#mainFrame`.

> CSS transition properties can be used without any prefix provider, but since the specification has only recently achieved stability, the vendor prefixes can still be necessary for browsers based on WebKit.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)

**and also**

Change the below css

```
 #mainFrame.fade-out {
     opacity:0;
 }
 #mainFrame.fade-in {
     opacity:1;
 }
```

to this and check once:

```
 .fade-out {
     opacity:0;
 }
 .fade-in {
     opacity:1;
 }
```

**UPDATE2:**  ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4788044/1577396))

Add `?wmode=opaque` to your youtube url. Working fine here :).

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h8ZkR/3/)

Comment: also check your browser support for transitions

Comment: @iBlue I updated my post. please check once. and also clear the cache of your browser.

Comment: @iBlue I highly suspect that there could be a possible bug in your code. please check developer tool once. and also what about the classes `fade-in` and `fade-out`? are they working properly in firefox?

Comment: ok...i just checked with mozilla developer console.The class is working.And i saw an odd thing, when i inspect the iframe using developer tool the iframe turns black.And then if i click fade in and fade out it works.

Comment: @iBlue I am not sure about it. Honestly, I just searched for your issue on stackoverflow. check the link which I provided it has more info about this issue.