# Overlap an Iframe using a DIV doesn't seem to work on Firefox

Tags: css, iframe, click

Can i overlap an iframe using a div so it is not clickable?

This is what i have (and doesn't work in Firefox)

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="do-not-allow-click"></div>
  <div class="iframe-container">
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/T4-PSYiYUzQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

And these are the CSS rules:

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 315px;
  width: 420px;
}

.do-not-allow-click {
  cursor: move;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.iframe-container {
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Which version of firefox are you referring to? It looks fine to me in 27.0.1

Comment: Josh: version is Firefox 28.0 (latest one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you embed a youtube link in an iFrame, the default wmode is windowed which apply a z-index greater then everything else and get overlay at the top.

To solve this append `wmode=opaque` to the source URL like this

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/T4-PSYiYUzQ?wmode=opaque
```

So your iframe code will be as below

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/T4-PSYiYUzQ?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Check this: [overlay opaque div over youtube iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820325/overlay-opaque-div-over-youtube-iframe)