# Overlay image on YouTube embed

Tags: html, css, youtube, overlay

I am trying to overlay an image on a YouTube embed on a website I am creating. The image specifically is a play button, which will turn orange when being hovered over. It looks like the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qm5h.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzOuB.png

Unfortunately, I have not figured out how to do this. I have read the same issue here, and in other places:
[overlay opaque div over youtube iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820325/overlay-opaque-div-over-youtube-iframe)

However, this has not worked for me at all. I've even tested this in both Firefox and Chrome, and still no luck. The custom play button does flash on screen for a moment, but then quickly disappears.

This is my CSS:

```
.youtubeplayer
{
    background-image: url('img/playbutton2.png') center no-repeat;
    z-index:100;
}
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<iframe class="youtubeplayer" width="700" height="455" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ScfXNmDkvHo?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: If you use vimeo movies, you can set colors...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below should give you a decent starting point, to refine for your purposes:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/y7ts6/1/)

HTML

```
<div>
    <iframe class="youtubeplayer" width="700" height="455" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ScfXNmDkvHo?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:700px;
}
div:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:39%;
    left:44%;
    height:60px;
    width:85px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:30px;
    background:#3AA8FF;
    transition:all 200ms ease-in;
}
div:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:44.5%;
    left:49%;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
}
div:hover:before {
    background:orange;
}
```

Comment: Just as an included bit, OP doesn't need to use an image to get what they want: http://jsfiddle.net/gC82G/

Comment: Weird, I tried that in JSfiddle and it wouldn't work... must have missed something.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will definitely use this as the base.