# Overlay div over YouTube iframe

Tags: css, iframe, youtube-api

I want to add a div over YouTube iframe, I have tried adding `wmode: "transparent"`, changing the z-index and nothing seems to be working for me any ideas

```
<div id="ytplayer"></div>
<div id="my_div"></div>
```

```
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '480',
      width: '853.333333',
      videoId: mMs_XJT6YFc,
      playerVars: {
        wmode: "transparent",
        controls: 0,
        showinfo: 0,
        rel: 0,
        modestbranding: 1,
        iv_load_policy: 3
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: already answered - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4788044/3289734

Comment: possible duplicate of [overlay opaque div over youtube iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820325/overlay-opaque-div-over-youtube-iframe)